# Amazon S3 Async Upload using Task library

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a windows form that upload file to Amazon S3. I tried to implement built in async method but seems not working fine so I think the best way would be to implement System.Threading.Tasks.

My actual code looks like this:

```
public void UploadFileAsync(string bucketName, CloudDocument doc, bool publicRead)
{
config = new AmazonS3Config();
            config.CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP;
            client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, config);

// Load stream from file location
            FileMode mode = FileMode.Open;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(doc.FullName, mode, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Create put object request
                TransferUtilityUploadRequest objectRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
                objectRequest.InputStream = fs;
                objectRequest.BucketName = bucketName;

                if (publicRead) objectRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

                objectRequest.Key = doc.KeyName + doc.FileName.Replace(' ', '_');

                objectRequest.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(UploadProgressEvent);

                transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
                IAsyncResult asyncResult = transferUtility.BeginUpload(objectRequest, new AsyncCallback(UploadCallBack), results);

                waitHandles.Add(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle);



                // Wait till all the requests that were started are completed.
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());
            }

            client.Dispose();

        }

}
private void UploadProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
        {
            if (UploadProgressChanged != null)
                UploadProgressChanged(this, e);
        }

private void UploadCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {

            Results results = result.AsyncState as Results;
            try
            {

                // If there was an error during the put attributes operation it will be thrown as part of the EndPutAttributes method.
                transferUtility.EndUpload(result);

                results.Successes++;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                results.Errors++;
            }
        }
```

Have anyone tried to implement Await / Async Task in order to upload async to amazon s3?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What does that code do?

Comment: The async, for a moment the UI is blocked.

Answer (score 4):

You can find instructions for [wrapping APM and EAP members into TAP members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx) on MSDN.

In summary, you use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to wrap `Begin`/`End` method pairs, something like this:

```
public static Task UploadAsync(this TransferUtility @this, TransferUtilityUploadRequest request)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(@this.BeginUpload, @this.EndUpload, request, null);
}
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
var task = transferUtility.UploadAsync(objectRequest);
tasks.Add(task);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I get an error:
Since 'AmazonS3Utility.UploadAsync(Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility, Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?

Comment: Updated to a non-`async` method.

Comment: Now the error is gone. Where do I have to place all my upload code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in the Developer Preview of the [AWS SDK 2.0 for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/). The source for the async extension class for the TransferUtility can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/v2-preview/AWSSDK_DotNet45/Amazon.S3/Transfer/TransferUtility.async.cs). Let us know if you have any feedback on the preview!

Thanks!